# PushSource filter pushing sample too for render

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directshow

I'm bit new to directshow. I'm using PushSource filter sample provided with DirectShow to push sequence of bmp image to avi file. But before that I'm trying to see whether filter is able to render the samples. The render is able to display just the first frame, though the filter is running properly and filling the buffers. I put `printf` at various stages to see the flow.
I feel that PushSource is running too fast and render is getting hanged.
Please provide some suggesting how to synchronize the two.
Also let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to miss time stamps, you are omitting them or possibly leaving garbage where they are supposed to be correct. You will want the pushing filter to stamp samples correctly, so that multiplexers and renderers have no doubts as for sample presentation times.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I was able to resolve the issue, there was some issue in my implementation. I was just adding one image to the sequence list. I fixed it and it worked fine